# React can't render array from component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have this component with some menu. In here there is some array iteration of menu items. I want to import this component to other `main` one but i'm receiving this error - `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`. When i'm remove this array iteration and leave simple link everything is fine. What is wrong?

**component:**

```
const LandingMenu = (props) => {
    return (
        props.data.map((element, _) =>
            <Link class="link" href={ element.target }>{ element.name }</Link>
        )
    )
};

export default LandingMenu;
```

**import**

```
<LandingMenu data={LANDING_CONTENT.menu} />
```

Comment: Tack on `join("")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A React component cannot return an array... it has to return a single element.

Wrapping your output in a DIV would likely work fine:

```
const LandingMenu = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data.map((element, _) =>
                <Link class="link" href={ element.target }>{ element.name }</Link>
            )}
        </div>
    )
};

export default LandingMenu;
```

Answer (score 2):

Components need to be wrapped in a root element. Your notation would be fine if it was a helper function in a different class.

So your LandingMenu needs to look like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        {props.data.map((element, _) =>
            <Link class="link" href={ element.target }>{ element.name }</Link>}
    </div>
    )
)
```

an alternative solution would be to have a render helper function inside whatever component is currently using `LandingMenu`

```
//SomeComponent
renderHelperFunction(data){
    return (
        {data.map((element, _) =>
            <Link class="link" href={ element.target }>{ element.name }</Link>}
    )
)

render(){
    return (...

          {this.renderHelperFunction(this.props.data)}

    ...)
}
```